# Openfire plugin Asterisk-IM not working

Tags: java, asterisk, sip, openfire

I am newbie in openfire as well as asterisk.

I want to configure openfire user with asterisk for that i install Asterisk-IM plugin.

> My scenario :- 1 user name - "100" is register in openfire & same user is created in asterisk/sip.conf file

After enable that plugin I can't connect my openfire user on port 5222 in any of the SIP client like, Pidgin, Spark, etc.

If i remove that plugin then openfire is working fine.

I have followed step to configure from below link,
http://gnu-linux.org/xmpp-integration-with-asterisk.html

## When i enable the module then i am getting below errors:

### Error log

```
2015.05.15 14:30:31 org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.NIOConnection - No ACK was received when sending stanza to: org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.NIOConnection@1f4b993 MINA Session: (0x00000003: nio socket, server, /xxx.xxx.x.xx:49409 => /xxx.xxx.x.xx:5222) 
2015.05.15 14:31:35 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [vanity2.jiveon.com] 
2015.05.15 14:35:48 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [vanity2.jiveon.com] 
2015.05.15 14:44:40 org.jivesoftware.database.SequenceManager - Autocreating jiveID row for type '101' 
2015.05.15 14:45:01 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [vanity2.jiveon.com] 
2015.05.15 14:45:18 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [vanity2.jiveon.com] 
2015.05.15 14:45:32 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out 
2015.05.15 14:45:33 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [vanity2.jiveon.com] 
2015.05.15 14:47:15 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [vanity2.jiveon.com] 
2015.05.15 14:47:21 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [vanity2.jiveon.com] 
2015.05.15 14:48:18 index.jsp - Failed to fetch RSS feed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [vanity2.jiveon.com] 
2015.05.15 14:48:51 org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager - No plugin loader found for asterisk-im
```

Does anybody know how can i solve my above issue?

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Do you use Openfire 3.10?

Comment: Yes. My openfire version is 3.10.0. Am I missing anything? I am really stuck here. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. It was the network issue as well as version issue.

You should check iptables for this port as in mine packets for port 5222 was dropped so I test with stopping iptables by,

**/etc/init.d/iptables stop**

and it's worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk plugin don't work under Openfire 3.10. 
Use the latest Openfire 3.9.* version.

You can download it here:

Windows (installer) http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=openfire/openfire_3_9_3.exe

Debian http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=openfire/openfire_3.9.3_all.deb

Mac http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=openfire/openfire_3_9_3.dmg

Comment: Your help is appreciable. I have tried with OPenfire 3.9.3 and all stuff gone smooth. The previous problem is resolved with this version.

Comment: Your help is appreciable. I have tried with Openfire 3.9.3. I have follow the same user scenario and now user show online by logging to Spark client.                                                                                                                                                 But now how to make call using openfire with asterisk.

Comment: I am really stuck here. Please anybody help me to solve this issue? I will really appreciate your efforts.